# How to make PHP5 emulate older version?

Tags: php

I'm writing a web app on my system using PHP5, but the app needs to be compatible with PHP4. Is there any way to emulate PHP4, or at least issue warnings?

Thanks.

Comment: If your production environment is PHP4, your development environment should be too. But in reality, neither should be anything less that PHP5.3.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately PHP4 is not (easily) available for my development distro. Anyway, other projects depend on PHP5, so I need to keep it around.

Comment: In that case, you should compile 2 versions from source for your dev environment. Derick Rethans showed one of the simplest ways to do this in a distro-agnostic way: http://derickrethans.nl/multiple-php-version-setup.html. Better still, use Gentoo :-)

Comment: Thanks for that link. I see PHP4 binaries and dependencies are available from the Debian archives. I'll give that a go with fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, if you avoid functions and arguments that were added in PHP5 (as shown in the documentation for each function), then it should work just fine with PHP4. PHP is good at backwards-compatibility like that.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is trying to trace where the incompatible code is, as the PHP4 production server doesn't give any details, just a blank page.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't do that on a production server. It's shared hosting anyway so I can't get at php.ini.

Comment: You can set it at runtime with `ini_set`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to emulate PHP4 that I'm aware of. You need to run your code in a real PHP4 environment. Here's what I'd suggest:

- Grab an old distro which includes a PHP4 package. Apparently, [Ubuntu Dapper (6.06) does.](http://valerio.della-porta.com/node/44)
- Install it into a VM (VirtualBox or VMWare) on your box.
- Create a shared directory for the VM which points to your app dir on the real box.
- Inside your VM, create a symlink from the webroot to the mount point of the shared directory.

Once that is done, you can more or less forget about the VM. All you need to do is keep it running. Change your code in your app dir as before. You can run it from your browser with the IP of the virtual machine.

(Perhaps you could even install an old version of XDebug in the VM and do proper remote debugging from within your IDE. But I don't know if XDebug is compatible with PHP4 at all.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the simpler solutions first though.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You will have to install PHP 4 on the machine to provide the runtime environment. Or, even better, convince the client that PHP 4 in 2012 is... outdated.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a go at installing PHP4 in parallel with PHP5 on my development machine; that might do the job.